# Facebook login with Django

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a Facebook login in my Django (Django 1.5 with Python 2.7.4) app and when I try to `INSERT` into my MySQL database the name of the location of the user who is logging in, the table saves a string with parentheses and a comma.

For example, if the name of the location (which I access serializing a JSON object and typing `facebookMember['location']['name'])` is "Turdera", when I look into my database the value stored is`"(u'Turdera',)"`. It only happens when I call the `Model.save()` function, so it doesn't happen when I put the location name directly on creating function `(Model.objects.get_or_create())`.

This is the JSON:

```
{u'username': u'nombre.apellido', u'first_name': u'Nombre',
 u'last_name': u'Apellido', u'verified': True,
 u'name': u'Nombre Apellido', u'locale': u'en_US',
 u'hometown': {u'id': u'104026979634226', u'name': u'Turdera'},
 u'work': [{u'position': {u'id': u'416940894990201',
                          u'name': u'Software Developer'},
            u'start_date': u'0000-00',
            u'employer': {u'id': u'2176879549', u'name': u'Empresa'}}],
 u'email': u'email@hotmail.com',
 u'updated_time': u'2013-08-09T17:30:17+0000', u'birthday': u'05/08/1987',
 u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/nombre.apellido',
 **u'location': {u'id': u'104026979634226', u'name': u'Turdera'}**,
 u'gender': u'male', u'timezone': -3,
 u'education': [{u'school': {u'id': u'18143905522',
                             u'name': u'ITMaster Professional Training'},
                 u'type': u'College'},
                {u'school': {u'id': u'1089762591',
                             u'name': u'Pontifical Catholic University'},
                 u'type': u'College'}], u'id': u'655273058'}
```

And this is the code of the save function:

```
        obj, created = Member.objects.get_or_create(id=long(facebookMember['id']))

        if (obj.first_login == None):
            obj.first_login=datetime.now()

        obj.first_name=facebookMember['first_name']
        obj.last_name=facebookMember['last_name']
        obj.email=facebookMember['email']
        obj.locale=facebookMember['locale']
        obj.access_token=facebookMember['access_token']
        obj.location=(facebookMember['location']['name'] if 'location' in facebookMember else None),
        obj.gender = Utils().getInitialFromGender(facebookMember['gender'])
        obj.date_of_birth = Utils().getDateAsYYYYMMDD(facebookMember['birthday']) 
        obj.last_login=datetime.now()
        obj.save()
```

I could remove the "u" but not the parentheses and the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you got a comma at the end of the line? That is making python think you have a tuple, not a string:

```
>>> t = "s" if True else "b"
>>> print t
s
>>> t = ("s" if True else "b")
>>> print t
s
>>> t = ("s" if True else "b"),
('s',)
```

so try:

```
obj.location=facebookMember['location'].get('name', None)
```